React JS WSO2 Asgardeo
I am using the @asgardeo/auth-react SDK to integrate my spa with Identity Server and when I authenticate and query the state object data it does not complete, apparently the authentication data is not being saved in the object.  Any solution for this that you can suggest to me.  Thank you.

Hi would it be possible to provide more context to your issue like your SDK configuration ?

Hi Alberto, could you please elaborate on how you are querying the state object? Also, are you being successfully redirected back to the application after authentication?
